# JS: unexpected behavior by dinamically created button's onclick function

Tags: javascript, function, scope

I am trying to create a calculator with buttons from 0 to 9. I created the buttons from code and I wanted the `0` button to append `0` to the display, the `1` button to append `1`, etc. However, every button appends `3` to the display.

I made this minimal example to illustrate the problem:

```js
var myDisplay = document.getElementById("display");

for (var i=0; i<3; i++){
  var elem = document.getElementById("buttons");
  elem.appendChild(newButtonWithText(i, function(){myDisplay.value += i;}));
}

function newButtonWithText(text,fun){
  var btn = document.createElement("button");       
  var t = document.createTextNode(text);     
  btn.appendChild(t);  
  btn.className= "btn btn-default";
  btn.onclick = fun;
  return btn;
}
```

```html
<input id="display"></input>
<div id="buttons"></div>
```

Comment: @gurvinder372—sure, but clicking any button writes "3".

Comment: please open i have answer

Comment: `var test = this.innerHTML;
myDisplay.value+= test;`